# Can't load image from URL with Picasso in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, picasso

I've been trying to use the Picasso library for one of my projects, and it didn't seem to work and I can't find a solution.

My code seems fine, and I created a new project just to test the library. Here's the code in the test project:

XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainAcitivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imagine;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagine = findViewById(R.id.imagine);
    Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imagine);

}
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Even with this simple project, the image does not load, and I can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I check **exception** in **Picasso**, if image is not loaded due to some **error**.

```
imagine = findViewById(R.id.imagine);
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(parent.getContext())
            .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                    // check here the exception
                }
            })
            .build();

picasso.load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
            .into(imagine);
```

Comment: Thank you, by printing the StackTrace in the Logcat I was able to find the error. In order to use android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml file, the minimum SDK must be 23. Mine was 22.

Comment: @RPT but in android docs it doesnt say anything about minSDK , and ive tried it 2 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic

Comment: @justArandomUser in the documentation it says that it was added in API level 23. As mine was 22, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the following code to load image,

```
 Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.imgplaceholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.imgplaceholder)
                    .into(ivProfilePicture)
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

> `get()`

with `with()`

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imagine);
```

[just like here](https://github.com/square/picasso/commit/e7e919232fe2b15772a7fcd9e15ead2304c66fae)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this method is deprecated. It's not usable anymore.