# How to setImageBitMap from url image in Internet?

Tags: android-studio

is it possible to convert url image to bitmap ?
and then use setImageBitMap() to set image to imageView ?
if you have any other way to store image from url image in sqlite, please tell me.

I used this function to convert url https to inputstream:

```
  public static  InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)  throws IOException {

        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("downloadImage" + ex.toString());
        }
        return stream;
    }
```

then i convert it to bitmap and add in my data:

```
public static ArrayList<Comics> initDataForComics() throws IOException {
        InputStream st = getHttpConnection("https://ibb.co/jfspG9S");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(st);
        data.add(new Comics("Sakamoto",bitmap));
        data.add(new Comics("Sakamoto",bitmap));
        data.add(new Comics("Sakamoto",bitmap));
        data.add(new Comics("Sakamoto",bitmap));
        data.add(new Comics("Sakamoto",bitmap));
        return data;

    }
```

in my recycler.viewholder i set like this :

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ComicsVH holder, int position) {
        Comics comics = lstComics.get(position);
        holder.titleComics.setText(comics.getName());
        holder.imgComics.setImageBitmap(comics.getImage());

    }
```

this is my comics class

```
public class Comics {
    //int id;
    String name;
    Bitmap image;
    //int category;
    //int views;
    //int likes;


    public Comics(String name, Bitmap image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

but it didn't work!,
my app can launch but imageview didn't display
[This is my app, the empty block on the left is where my image'll display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kn5p.png)

Comment: Use Picasso Library. See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60465498/16765223 and Picasso library: https://square.github.io/picasso/